# How to show $m(A) = m(A \backslash Z)$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $m$  be the Lebesgue measure, and $Z$ a set of measure zero, $A \subset \mathbb{R}$

Then intuitively, $m(A) = m(A \backslash Z)$

How to show this?

**Attempt:** $m(A \backslash Z) = m(A \cap Z^c)$ Is there a way to turn that $\cap$ upside down and use countable additivity?

Comment: $A-Z \subset A$, and so $m(A-Z) = m(A) - m(Z) = m(A)$. Or you can say that $A-Z$ and $Z$ are disjoint subsets which union to $A$, so $m(A-Z) + m(Z) = m(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m(A)=m(A \cap Z)+ m(A \cap Z^C)$

but we know that $0 \leq m(A \cap Z) \leq m(Z)=0$.

Hence $m(A)=m(A \cap Z^C).$

Comment: Okay, and the first line holds because we already know that $Z$ is measurable, therefore the caratheodory condition holds $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap Z) + m^*(A \cap Z^c)$ and $m^*$ coincides with $m$ right?

Comment: yup. that is right.